# How to get Month Name from DateTime vlaue in CAML

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query, date-time

I have a requirement to show user Month name of the date on which user uploaded the file.

My date time value is coming in dd/mm/yyyy 00:00 AM.

Someone please help  me how to move forward on this.

Comment: Are you deploying a custom component (i.e. web part, user control, etc.) in which you are building the CAML query or are you leveraging an out-of-the-box SharePoint web part, such as the Content Query Web Part (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx)? Please also indicate what version of SharePoint you are working with. There are a few options depending on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I am deploying visual web part and using CAML query to get the data from document library. And I am working in SharePoint 2013 environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for DateTime field formatting for results you get through CAML Query:

```
DateTime dtDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list["DateTimeField"]);
spnDate.InnerText = dtDate.ToString("dd-MMMM");
```

DateTime Formatting reference link in c# : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx